# Get Disk Usage in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the current disk usage activity and display it in an xaml form. I have attempted to google how to do it, but everyone just talks about MB's available/used.
I want to display the percentage shown of disk active time in task manager for windows 10.

I have attempted to find a way to grab the info with `Get-Counter` as well as `collect1` but neither of these seem work and I am lost on a starting point.

Comment: So you have nothing at all yet? What do you expect from us now? You might re-review th following help articles: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Hot to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  ... and may I add the question whatfor do you like to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did actually find a solution eventually. I was looking for Disk Active Time not usage. There is no way to grab the information easily, but I found some code online which I was able to modify to my needs. I cannot remember the source otherwise I would site it.

```
$Sleep=10
$Idle1=$DiskTime1=$T1=$Idle2=$DiskTime2=$T2=1

$Disk = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk `
-filter "name= 'C:' "
[Double]$Idle1 = $Disk.PercentIdleTime
[Double]$DiskTime1 = $Disk.PercentDiskTime
[Double]$T1 = $Disk.TimeStamp_Sys100NS

start-Sleep $Sleep

$Disk = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk `
-filter "name= 'C:' "
[Double]$Idle2 = $Disk.PercentIdleTime
[Double]$DiskTime2 = $Disk.PercentDiskTime
[Double]$T2 = $Disk.TimeStamp_Sys100NS

$PercentIdleTime =[math]::Round((($Idle2 - $Idle1) / ($T2 - $T1)) * 100)
$PercentDiskTime =[math]::Round((($DiskTime2 - $DiskTime1) / ($T2 - $T1)) * 100)
```

`$PercentDiskTime` reflects what you see in the graph on Task Manager as the Active time best.
Adjusting `$Sleep` can provide an avg over time. I find anything longer than 10 seconds and under 3 is too inaccurate for real time data.

For anyone who comes to the question looking for actual Disk Usage as a percentage:

```
[string[]]$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Disk = Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk -filter "deviceid='C:'"
$FreeSpacePer = ((($Disk.Freespace /1Gb -as [float]) / ($Disk.Size / 1Gb -as [float]))*100) -as [int]
$SpaceUsePer = 100 - $FreeSpacePer
```

Comment: Could be missing it, but what is the use in obtaining `[string[]]$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME` in your find disk usage as a percentage? Can't seem to see where that variable is used post that line.